# How to clear the weights on the vertices from a group of bones?

Tags: animation, rigging

How to clear the weights on the vertices from a group of bones and leave only one bone to affect these vertices, which at the time of the operation is active, selected?

Comment: You can remove from all groups, but I'm not sure there's a way to remove from all groups except (selected or locked) one (or several ones), it would be interesting though

Comment: How can I remove weights from a group of selected vertices from all vertex groups one by one or in a couple of clicks?

Comment: you can select some vertices (or all the vertices) in the 3D view, then in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, choose the vertex group you want the vertices to be removed from and click the Remove button under the vertex groups list, or in the menu on the right of the vertex groups list (down arrow icon) choose Remove From All Groups. Does it answer?

Comment: Yes, it helped me, thanks) In order to clear a group of vertices from weights from all groups, it is now clear how. But the question of how to clear weights from all groups except one is still relevant.

Comment: Sure, I think it should be a feature, like if you lock a group and Remove From All Groups it protects the group, or other solution, maybe suggest it to Right Click Select

Comment: blocking a group doesn't help. i checked in practice. I think there is simply no such function, but I don't know how to find out for sure.
 "maybe suggest it to Right Click Select " - What do you mean here?
Feature? Do you mean addon or just want to say that such a function should be present in blender?

Comment: yes I meant you could suggest the idea to Blender developers through this site: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: Oh, cool idea, thanks for the clarification, I just haven't done this before - did not offer ideas for development

Answer (score 1):

Select All vertexes you wnat to edit, edit weight settings in side bar, click "Copy" and your edit settings distribute on all selected vertexes.

[image]